# Bundle iOS settings app screenshots

Tags: ios

An app will only work correctly if user setup the app's notification settings correctly in iOS settings.
Is it OK to bundle screenshots into the app itself, screenshots that depict the related screens of iPhone/etc iOS setup?
...or will Apple reject this if screenshots of the iOS settings app are not allowed in apps?

I don't find anything saying that this would be a problem at https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html
But <s>something</s> guts tells me this could be disallowed.

Comment: Guts. Guts. Guts. - lolz!! @Jonny, I wish code runs as per our Gut-Feelings!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

> 10.2 Apps that look similar to Apps bundled on the iPhone, including the App Store, iTunes Store, and iBookstore, will be rejected.

I guess you're worrying about that Apple will think your screenshots of the iOS Settings app makes your app look similar to the bundled Settings app?

In my opinion, if you wrap those screenshots nicely (e.g. with a frame, shadows etc) so users know that it's a screenshot, there's no problem with it.

Comment: I'll go with this answer. If all goes well I'll check it too.

Comment: You can create an HTML page which will serve as a tutorial/help page for your app users. You can add screenshots to demonstrate the steps to change settings. Display this HTML page on first launch of your application. This will save your guts for next app! ;)